# What interpretation can have a negative conditional entropy in quantum information?

Tags: quantum-information, entropy, quantum-interpretations, quantum-computer

So, I'm studying the basics in quantum information and many texts and papers have interpretations for entropy, relative entropy and conditional entropy, but none has an interpretation for a negative conditional entropy, say systems $A$ and $B$. Can someone help me understand what this means and the implications it has?

Comment: There are many textbooks, articles and blog posts written on this subject, which is a rather general one. Please formulate a more specific question.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0505062

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, there are different ways to interpret the idea of negative conditional entropy in quantum information theory. Here is just one that I find particularly elegant and intuitive:

The famous [Landauer's erasure principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle) reveals a deep connection between information and thermodynamics: namely the erasing of a system with entropy $H(S)$ requires **you to do work** $W(S)=k_{B}T.H(S)$ where $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant and T is the temperature of the bath used in the process of erasing.

[Lidia et al.](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature10123) extended this principle for conditional entropies H(S|O) where the entropy of the system depends on the information an external observer has about it. As $W(S|O)=k_{B}T.H(S|O)$ and the entropy $H(S|O)$ can be negative, erasing a system can actually result in a **net gain of work** in a quantum setting.